# xpath does not select nodes with class using etree

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I'm trying to get some elements from a svg using xpath. I'm trying to get nodes via their class. For example:

```
<path d="M 5624850,7744480 A 355600,355600 0 0,1 5624850,8455680 A 355600,355600 0 0,1 5624850,7744480" stroke-width="7620" fill="none" class="outline LAY26"/>
```

So, if I want the class with 'outline' and 'L26', I do the following one:

```
elements = self.node.findall(".//*[@class='outline LAY26']")
```

However I always get an empty array. The nodes that I'm looking for can be nested. So I think i'm looking just in the first level, maybe I'm wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using elementree - have you tried just `self.node.findall("[@class='outline LAY26']")` ?

Comment: @JonClements yeah, and I get nothing.

Comment: http://pivotallabs.com/users/alex/blog/articles/427-xpath-css-class-matching Try this way. `findall(".//*[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' outline ' and contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' LAY26 '))]")`

Comment: @iMom0 it says the syntaxis is incorrect :(

Comment: @iMom0 That syntax isn't valid for `xml.etree.ElementTree` as it only supports limited `XPath` - and wouldn't apply anyway, as it's a valid literal comparison instead of looking for a class name inside a list of classes